# how to retrieve channel id of Apache Hop pipeline at runtime

Tags: kettle, pentaho-data-integration, apache-hop

I have a data pipeline, which writes data from a csv file into a staging database table( SQL Server).
The logging is set up to collect all data from a pipeline execution in the same database.
In order to be able to link the newly created data record in the database to a logging data of a particular job,
I would like to add a column **Job_id** to my data table. This would allow me to retrieve the logging data that has been collected when this record has been created.
The logging data has fields like *pipelineLogChannelId* , that seems to be the unique runtime id of a pipeline. Is it possible to get that id inside the running pipeline, so I can set it as a value for a column in my target database table ?

I tried different transformations, variables. the most promising is "Execution Information" but this is quite slow, and I could not find a setting that returns the job id of the pipeline.
The "get Execution IDs" operation type with limit set to 1 and include children set to 0 returns the channel id of the next transformation, but not the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still looking for this, there are internal variable names that could help you get the result you want.
*${Internal.Pipeline.ID}* This will contain the logchannel of the pipeline it is asked in.
*${Internal.Workflow.ID}* the same but for a workflow

This information was derived from the sourcecode, it's not publicly documented